# Инспекция генератора имён

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Написал я программу, выложил на гитхаб (https://github.com/KaPaHgaIII/namegenerator). Нет ли такого места, где можно показать свой код более опытным людям, чтобы указали на недочёты?

Comment: До кучи, обращаю внимание, что коммитить в репозиторий файлы проекта вашей IDE (*.iml, .idea/*) - плохая практика.

Коммитить бинарники библиотек (lib/*.jar) - тоже не хорошо (кроме случаев когда бинарник очень уникальный), лучше научиться пользоваться maven.

Comment: hashcode.ru перебрасывает на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/. Так что по сути вопрос актуальный. Я так и не нашел подходящего места.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: теперь подходящее место — это Stack Overflow на Русском. Подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)

```
cmdArguments.getGender().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase().equals("m") //жуть

cmdArguments.getGender() == Genders.MALE //старые добрые enum
```

а вот в getGender нужно писать что-то типо этого

```
switch(gender) {
   case "male": return Gender.MALE;
   //и т.п.
```

2)

```
   Random randomizer = new Random(System.nanoTime()); //мелкая придирка, но System.nanoTime() писать не обязательно
```

3) в

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmdArguments.getCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(engine.generateName(cmdArguments.getLength()));
}
```

System.out.println лучше выносить в отдельный метод, причём лучше в отдельный класс (правило mvc)

4)

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

меняем на

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    System.err.println(e); //обратите внимание на err
}
```

5)

```
readData("male_names.txt");
```

здесь тоже бы хорошо было бы заюзать enum. А вдруг в будущем вы будете считывать данные не с файла, а с интернета? Будете url каждый раз указывать?

6) огромное количество

```
s.substring(i, i + 2);
```

А почему +2, а не +3? Не помешал бы мелкий комментарий рядом

7) Отдельное текстовое пояснение как работает алгоритм. Иначе он будет понятен только вам

**0)** Но главное, после моих рекомендаций не превратиться в Бориса из известной статьи [Как два программиста хлеб пекли](http://habrahabr.ru/post/153225/)

Comment: 4) А разве catch all хорошая практика?

Comment: @VladD, ну раз в catch -е ничего не делается, кроме как печатается ошибка, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: @danpetruk: в старом варианте исключения ловились только те, которые могли возникнуть вследствие объективных причин: нет файла, ошибка чтения и т. п. В новом варианте обращение к несуществующему индексу или похожий баг в программе не приведёт к аварийному выходу, а спокойно проглотится и проигнорируется. `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`.

Comment: спасибо за потраченное время и за ценные замечания

Answer (score 5):

Ох, не люблю всех этих телепаций уровня "введите то, введите сё, введите хрень ту экзит". Чем стандартная командная строка не угодила-то?

```
-g, --gender=    m[ale], f[emale], b[oth]
-l, --length=    name length
-n, --number=    number of names to generate
```

Понятно и без лишних телодвижений. Тем более что стандартный GNU getopt() для Java [существует давно](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html).

Comment: @klopp, спасибо за совет, переделал, использовал args4j